# How to save variable in custom layer in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wI want to create a (4,1) dimension matrix to multiply with inputs with (4,) dimension in my custom layer. So I do as the following:

class MyLayer(Layer):

```python
def __init__(self, output_dim = 4, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    k1 = K.variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='k1')
    k2 = K.variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='k2')
    k3 = K.variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='k3')
    k4 = K.variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='k4')
    weights = tf.stack([k1,k2,k3,k4], name='weight_stack')
    weights = tf.expand_dims(weights,1)
    weights = tf.expand_dims(weights, 1)
    weights = tf.expand_dims(weights, 1)
    weights = tf.expand_dims(weights, 1)
    self.kernel=tf.nn.softmax(weights,name='weights_softmax')


    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

def call(self, inputs):
    self.inputs = inputs
    P = tf.multiply(self.inputs, self.kernel)
    P = tf.add_n([P[0],P[1],P[2],P[3]])
    self.shape = P.shape
    return P

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape ):
    return (input_shape, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

I call it as followed:

```python
x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
x = MyLayer(name = "weight_matrix")(x)
```

It works when I train the Network with this self designed layers. However, when I save it with callbacks as followed:

```python
keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(self.checkpoint_path,
                                        verbose=0, save_weights_only=True)
```

I found that I can't reload the "weights"(means k1 to k4) when I try to reload the model.
And I take a look into the file which save the model, I can't find the weights for the "weight_matrix".

If I am not doing it right, how can I fix it or how to implement it in keras? Thx.

Comment: Is this intended to be a trainable weight?

Comment: @DanielMöller Yes, it is a trainable weight, it suppose to get gradient descent from the loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere you're calling `self.add_weight`.

Your layer simply doesn't have weights.

In `build`:

```py
def build(self, input_shape):
    def customWeights(shape, dtype=None):

        #k1 = K.variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='k1')
        #k2 = K.variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='k2')
        #k3 = K.variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='k3')
        #k4 = K.variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='k4')
        #weights = tf.stack([k1,k2,k3,k4], name='weight_stack')
        weights = K.ones((4,))  
           #you can also use the shape passed to this function to build a flexible layer


        #weights = tf.expand_dims(weights,1)
        #weights = tf.expand_dims(weights, 1)
        #weights = tf.expand_dims(weights, 1)
        #weights = tf.expand_dims(weights, 1)
        weights = K.reshape(weights,(-1,1,1,1,1))

        #this should be applied later
        #return tf.nn.softmax(weights,name='weights_softmax')

        return weights

    self.kernel= self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=notBeingUsedButItMayBeGoodForFlexibleLayers,
                                  initializer=customWeights,
                                  trainable=True)

    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!
```

In `call` you call the `softmax` on your weights:

```py
def call(self, inputs):
    #don't call this! You're replacing an important property of the layer
    #self.inputs = inputs

    kernel = K.softmax(self.kernel)

    P = tf.multiply(inputs, kernel)
    P = tf.add_n([P[0],P[1],P[2],P[3]])

    #not sure if this is a good idea either
    #self.shape = P.shape

    return P
```

Comment: Thx a lot!!! I still get wonder since you have call self.add_weight to initialize the weight matrix, can I do it like :  `self.kernel= self.add_weight(name='kernel', shape=(4,1,1,1,1), initializer=customWeights, trainable=True)`  to implement it (In this way, maybe I will need a new keras initializer?), Does this do anything harmful to my Layer?

Comment: It`s ok. Actually, I think doing this is more correct than what I did. If it works and you consider that this answers your question, please check it as answered :)

Comment: Thx a lot for your help